# Converting MySQL ANSI input to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I've decided to switch my web app from ANSI to UTF-8. After converting the encoding of my hardcoded files in Notepad++ (which does a *conversion*, not only changing the character set) and setting a new meta tag for UTF-8, I now need to convert my database data.

This data has been inputted on ANSI forms, but is stocked as utf8_general_ci according to phpMyAdmin. Obviously I can't just change the MySQL stocking encoding then, because it's already the right one (apparently?).

On the web pages, my accent characters (é, à, etc.) loaded from the DB appear as �.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are  having a problem in the *database*? Are you sure the characters don't get broken when output on the web site, e.g. because of a database connection defaulting to ISO-8859-1?

Comment: That's a possibility. I'm far from an encoding master. Could you post a fix as an answer instead of a comment? :) I'm using PHP.

Comment: Actually, since new input works fine, I'm really just looking for a conversion, not a change in the configuration.

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution from [this blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/):

```
UPDATE `ressources` SET `title` = CONVERT(CONVERT(`title` USING binary) USING utf8);
```

However, I get 0 rows affected on phpMyAdmin. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problems, but changing the sql connection to utf-8 helped :)

```
mysql_set_charset("utf-8", $mysql_link);
```